# Can @transactionalEventListener be @transactional?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've just seen such fragment of code:

```
@TransactionalEventListener
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void listenSomethingChanged(SomethingChangedEvent event)
```

The event contains some persistent entities which have lazy-loaded fields. As a result NPE occurs. when accessing thos lazy fields within `listenSomethingChanged`

Would it create separate transaction for listener?
If there are entities if fields of event, would they become persistent again?